# center main picture on slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

i am new here

I trying to work in javascript and css for display a slider with many picture, visible next to each other.

How to center the main image, in my slider when I click on the next or previous button?

no matter what i did it doesn't work the way i want!

Sorry if my english is not good.

js code

```
const urls = ['../portfolio/img/perenoel.png', '../portfolio/img/monavenir.png',  '../portfolio/img/kitsitter.png',
'../portfolio/img/kitsitter.png',  '../portfolio/img/kitsitter.png',  '../portfolio/img/kitsitter.png','../portfolio/img/kitsitter.png','../portfolio/img/kitsitter.png','../portfolio/img/perenoel.png', '../portfolio/img/perenoel.png', 


];

const carrousel =  document.getElementById('slider');
const figure = document.createElement('figure');
const div2 = document.createElement('div');
const figureid = "figureid" ;
figure.id = figureid;
const btn_previous = document.createElement('button');
const btn_next = document.createElement('button');
btn_next.classList.add("next");
btn_previous.classList.add("previous");


figure.classList.add("figure");
carrousel.appendChild(figure);
figure.appendChild(div2);

for (a = 0; a< urls.length; a++){


const img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = urls[a];
const num = a+1;
div2.appendChild(img);
img.classList.add('imgcarousel');



carrousel.appendChild(btn_previous);
carrousel.appendChild(btn_next);


let current_image = 2;
const imgcarousel = document.getElementsByClassName('imgcarousel')[a];
const div =  document.getElementsByClassName('description')[a];

    img.classList.add(num);  



    div.classList.add(num);

const classnum =  num;
const figure_width = figure.getBoundingClientRect().width;
const img_width = imgcarousel.getBoundingClientRect().height;
// div2.style.marginLeft="-5%";



function rotation (){
 
    if(classnum == current_image){       
      
        imgcarousel.classList.toggle('actif');
        imgcarousel.style.height="80%";   
        // imgcarousel.style.zIndex="10";
        imgcarousel.style.boxShadow="1px 1px 12px #555";      
        div.style.display="block";   
        // imgcarousel.style.marginLeft="0%";  
        

    }   
    else {  
        imgcarousel.style.height="50%";   
        imgcarousel.style.boxShadow="0 0 0";     
        div.style.display="none"; 
        // imgcarousel.style.zIndex="7";  
     }
   
    }
     

    function nextshift(){
        if(classnum == current_image - 1){;
            div2.appendChild(div2.firstChild);           
      }        
  
    }

    function previousshift(){     
    if(classnum == current_image){
         div2.insertBefore(div2.lastChild, div2.firstChild);        
      }
            }
       
            rotation();  




    btn_next.addEventListener('click', function () {
        ++current_image;
        
         rotation();   
         nextshift();
        
    if (current_image  > urls.length) {
         current_image = 0;
         
     }
// div2.style.marginLeft= +"5%";
  
   
   });

    btn_previous.addEventListener('click', function () {
            --current_image;           
            rotation();
            previousshift();     

      if (current_image < 1) {
        current_image = urls.length+1;   
      }                    
  
     });   
  
}
```

css code

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    /* font-family: Montserrat; */
}


body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
   font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}




nav{
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color :#474787;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
 } 

i{
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 5%;
}
 
 nav>li{
    list-style: none;
    padding:20px;
   
  
} 

nav>li>a{
    color:white;
    margin-left: 15%;
    display: flex;
} 

nav>li>a>i{
font-size: 1.5em;
} 


nav>li:hover{
   background-color: black;
   transition :0.4s;
} 


main{
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding:1px 16px;
    margin-top:0;
}



footer{
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
    padding-top:1%;
    padding-bottom:1%;
    background-color: #2c2c54;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0;
    bottom:0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:10%;

}

article{
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:5%;
    width:80%;
margin-left:15%;
  }
```

and this html :

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./css/realisation.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e087129262.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    <nav>

    <i class="fas fa-bars"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
  
        
            <li><a href="index.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i><p>Accueil</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="realisation.php"><i class="far fa-images"></i> <p>Réalisation</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="experience.php" > <i class="fas fa-certificate"></i> <p>Experience</p></a></li>
            <li><a href="formation.php"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i><p>Formation</p></a></li>
        
    </nav>

    <main>
 
         <article class="projet">
                  <h1>Mes réalisations</h1>
                  
                     <section id="slider">      


                     </section>    
                     <div class="papanoel description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Monpapanoel.com</h2>
                           <p>C'est un site pour faire patienter les enfants jusqu'à noël, ils peuvent jouer à un jeux, 
                                 lire une histoire ou appeler le père noël et télécharger la conversation. 
                                 Conception, Réalisation de la charte graphique (le logo existait déjà), Intégration sur wordpress.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/JS/PHP/MYSQL/WORDPRESS/ELEMENTOR/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="monpapanoel.com"><div>voir le site</div></a>

                     </section>
                     </div>
                     <div class="monavenir description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Monavenir.com</h2>
                           <p>Le site permet de prendre contact avec des voyants pour leur poser des questions sur leur avenir. On 
                                 peut y acheter des crédits. Conception, Réalisation de la charte graphique (le logo existait déjà), Intégration sur wordpress.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/JS/WORDPRESS/ELEMENTOR/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="monavenir.com"><div>voir le site</div></a>
                           
                     </section>
                     </div>
                     <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div> <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kitsiter description">
                        <section>
                           <h2>Kitsiter</h2>
                           <p>Création de la charte graphique, logo, interface et intégration sur angular sur le thème des petsitters.
                              </p>
                              <span>HTML/CSS/ANGULAR/JS/ADOBE XD/PHOSOTSHOP/ILLUSTRATOR</span>
                           <a class="link" href="mettreliengitversleprojet"><div>voir le projet</div></a>
                           
                        </section>
                        </div>
                          
            </article>
            
            <article class="print">
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/ecurie.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/pinit.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/potager.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/gouter.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/artsacrer.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/osteo.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/mystere.jpg"></div>
             <div><img src="../portfolio/img/arbre.jpg"></div>
            </article> 

    </main>
    <footer>copyright 2020 julie henriet</footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/carrousel.js"></script></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

thank you very much

Comment: Please add the minimal CSS and HTML to reproduce. [mcve]

Comment: it is done for css and html

Comment: apparently I forgot just a justify content center in my css :)